# How to pass the value got from google places api to another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-places-api

Hi i have developed an app using google places api. It displays the nearby department stores.

Now i need to pass the name of the store to another activity when i click on it.

Can anyone tell me how to do it i searched the net and did not find many solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.class,Second.class);
i.putExtra("name",selected_store_name);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: didnt work it gave an error on selected_store_name telling to add it as final but i cant add it as final it gives error in other places... @Muralinganesan...

Comment: paste your `logcat` error

Comment: this is my [logcaterror](http://pastebin.com/Hk1Kns2R)

Comment: how will u pass `value` one `Activity` to another `Activity`.

Comment: i added my code @Muraliganesan

Comment: where you add your code @Jayant Shinde

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23501/discussion-between-muraliganesan-and-jayant-shinde)

Answer (score 0):

either your intent value is not getting passed to other activity i.e. null pointer exception or you haven't fetched the value in activity